# Why does adding a bang make create work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails convention of adding a bang to the end of a method makes it throw an exception if it fails. But my experience isn't matching that behavior.

My controller for a many-to-many relationship (an audit trail). The relationship object cannot be created, only updated by posting events to the audit trail object.  (Which means you create by updating...)

I have a User object and a Foo object I'll call the relationship Bar.

```
    bar=Bar.where(:user_id=>params[:user_id]).where(:foo_id=>params[:foo_id]).first
    if bar
        authorize! :update, bar
    else
        user=User.find(params[:user_id])
        authorize! :bar_create, user
        foo=Foo.find(params[:foo_id])
        bar=Bar.create!(:user_id=>user.id, :foo_id=>foo.id)
    end
```

The `create` method does not work. I debugged, and `bar.save` worked fine, but the entire point of `create` is to avoid having to make that second call to save.  I experimented, and discovered that `create!` works just fine.

Edit:

As I continued on, I discovered that `create!` did *not*, in fact, always save.  No errors in the underlying object, just mysteriously not saved.

I've had to do a `create` call followed by a `save` call, which... honestly, I just don't understand.

Edit:  Per request, adding model code -- simplified to the relevant statements by removing unnecessary methods, validation calls, and the like.  (While writing this, I noticed that I haven't yet added the has_many :through calls, but... doesn't seem like those should be relevant to the issue at hand.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password


    has_many :progresses

end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :foo

  has_many :bar_events

  validates :user, :presence=>true
  validates :foo, :presence=>true


  scope :user_id, -> (user_id){ where user_id: user_id}
  scope :foo_id, -> (foo_id){ where foo_id: foo_id}
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: That meaning of `!` is Rails-specific. Ruby convention for bang methods normally means the operation happens in-place.

Comment: @sevenseacat what do you mean by 'in-place', and corrected.

Comment: Think of `gsub` vs. `gsub!` - `gsub` will return the altered string, `gsub!` will modify the original string.

Comment: @sevenseacat ah, now I understand.  And feel stupid for not remembering that.

Comment: No need to feel stupid :) Your understanding is right, in Rails the `create`, `save` and `update` methods return false in case of validation error, and `create!`, `save!` and `update!` methods raise exception in case of validation error. But all of them are supposed to save to database when no error occur. So your call to `create` should not need an additional call to `save`

Comment: It's detailed here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#validations So yes your issue is real and weird, I can't understand why you have that

Comment: Only thing I think off is association error while incorrectly set associations in models. Please paste your relevant models code

Comment: The non relevant code you removed didn't happend to have a before_save/before_create did it?

Comment: @FrederickCheung users had an after_initialize method, but since the user's object isn't being updated, I didn't see it as relevant.  The Bar class is essentially complete, just anonymized.

Comment: I suppose another problem would be a column whose name shadows an internal method (this usually causes DangerousAttributeError to be raised). A method with such a name clash could also do it

Answer (score 0):

There is a validation error or more in one of the associations in Bar `foo` or `user`. Try inspecting those objects:

```
bar=Bar.create!(:user_id=>user.id, :foo_id=>foo.id)
puts bar.errors.inspect, bar.user.errors.inspect, bar.foo.errors.inspect
```

That will print the errors of all those objects to the terminal running `rails server`. The only reason create would not save is due to validation errors in itself or nested associations.

Comment: I did debug and inspect for errors.  There weren't any.  Hence why the calls to `save` and `save!` work properly.  For some reason, `create` and `create!` aren't saving, even though they should, but there aren't any errors to explain why.